# Routing messages from IoT Hub to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a bunch of sensors (currently 350) that are sending a total of around 500000 messages a day to an Azure IoT Hub. The sensors are grouped in to differently sized studies and i need to report on those studies each month.

I've tried to use stream analytics but couldn't find a way to dynamically route the messages to their respective locations. I dont want to have to add an individual output for each study.

Can anyone suggest a way to get these messages in to an Azure Data Lake so that each study's messages get put in their own folder eg \{StudyID}\{Year}\{Month}\[Message Data].

Comment: Post such questions in comments section of learn.microsoft.com blogs (in related Data lake or IOT or Stream analytics topics), you ll get rapid response or pointers..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience. At this time, you cannot add custom variable in the output structure when exporting data from ASA to Azure Data Lake. 
We're keep this request in our backlog for future updates of the product.

You can also add suggestions in our User Voice portal here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270577-azure-stream-analytics

Thanks,
JS